# Sum or Multiply in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

How can sum or Multiply row in SQL Server?
For example...

[image]

I want to Sum Number1 and Number2 (1 + 4) and automatically number 5 will be added to Number3 column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `Number3` to always contain the sum of `Number1` and `Number2`, then define it as a computed column.  In the `create table` statement, say:

```
Number3 as (Number1 + Number2)
```

This will ensure that the third number is always the sum of the other two.  Automatically.

Comment: Yes, number 3 will always be the sum of Number1 and Number2. It gives me error. It says "Incorrect syntax near AS."

This is my table...

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [Id]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Number1]  FLOAT NULL,
    [Number2]   FLOAT NULL,
    [Number3] FLOAT NULL AS (Number1 + Number2) ,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);`

Comment: It's ok. I fixed it. I has to delete 'FLOAT NULL'

Comment: Great insight as usual Gordon. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
update
  t
set
  t.Number3 = t.Number1 + t.Number2
from
  mytable t
```

As @JoelCoehoorn very insightfully suggests, perhaps you want to include the value of `Number3` in which case it would be:

```
t.Number3 = t.Number3 + t.Number1 + t.Number2
```

Comment: "`5 will be **added** to the Number3 column`" He may want this instead: `t.Number3 = t.Number3 + t.Number1 + t.Number2`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   Number1 ,
   Number2 ,

   (Number1 + Number2 ) as 'Total'
FROM yourTableName
```

Comment: You are creating a new column, not changing the value of an existing one

Comment: Please don't just write code in an answer. Explain what it does and why it works that way.

Comment: Thank you @d_inevitable for your suggestion .My answer so simple for that reason you give me down-vote Sir ? :(

Comment: Hahahh ..its okay Sir ...But my answer is correct as far i know ?

Comment: I did not downvote either, but I think its clear that OP wanted to be able to update or keep the summed value.  Your query creates it, but doesnt keep it in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If the behavior never changes, you could also make "Number3" a computed column.

Column Definition something like:

Number3 AS Number1 + Number2 + 5

Comment: I like you're idea, but it would be `Number3 AS Number1 + Number2`.  5 is simply the example result.

Comment: @paqogomez , It gives me error. It says "Incorrect syntax near AS."

This is my table...

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [Id]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Number1]  FLOAT NULL,
    [Number2]   FLOAT NULL,
    [Number3] FLOAT NULL AS (Number1 + Number2) ,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);`

Comment: It's ok. I fixed it. I has to delete 'FLOAT NULL' . Thank You.